# xlwings: Read range as list of dictionaries

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlwings

Is it possible to use xlwings to read an Excel range as a list of dictionaries?

Say I have my data in Excel like:

[image: excel data structure]

I want to read it as:

```
[{'Name': 'Joan', 'Age': 45}, {'Name': 'Ali', 'Age': 18}, {'Name': 'Mustafa', 'Age': 37}]
```

I guess I'm looking for something that works a bit like csv.DictReader does for csv files.

If this isn't possible I can read in as a list of lists using .expand('horizontal') and then create the dictionaries after. I just didn't want to do that if there's a built in method already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary converter
The dictionary converter turns two Excel columns into a dictionary. If the data is in row orientation, use transpose:

```
>>> sht = xw.sheets.active
>>> sht.range('A1:B2').options(dict).value
{'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0}
>>> sht.range('A4:B5').options(dict, transpose=True).value
{'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0}
```

Note: instead of dict, you can also use OrderedDict from collections.